# Tcl: faster way to search a large list

Tags: search, tcl

**Problem:**

lsearch is increasing the runtime when searching a large list. Can the speed be increased?

```
if { [lsearch -exact $exclusion_list $cell ] >= 0 } { return 0 }
```

The list is 50000 elements long.

Comment: Can you store your data as a sorted list? If the list is not already sorted can you rewrite your code to make sure it is always sorted?

Comment: I've had some success migrating big lists to SQLite. Fast insert, delete, sort, and search.

Comment: If the values are unique you could try using a dictionary. I think the internal representation is a hash map, which should be fast.

Comment: I had written my own proc to uniquify the list. After using [lsort -unique $list], the runtime is a lot better. Thanks

Comment: Make sure you're using `-sorted` with `lsearch` too, not just sorting the list.

Answer (score 2):

If you sort the list, you can use `lsearch -sorted $exclusion_list $cell`, which uses a binary search for **O(log N)** runtime as opposed to the normal linear search's **O(N)**.

If you're doing a lot of lookups in the same list, you can get further gains (As always, benchmark with real data to see for sure) by storing the list elements in a `dict` hash table and getting **O(1)** lookups. Something like:

```
# Build a dict from the list
set exclusion_dict [dict create]
foreach elem $exclusion_list {
    dict set exclusion_dict $elem 1
}

# Later in code that processes a lot of cells
if {[dict exists $exclusion_dict $cell]} { return 0 }
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, `lsearch` assumes that the list is unsorted. In that case, the only available search strategy it knows is to do a linear scan (from front to back because you gotta have *some* strategy).

However, if you tell it that the list is sorted then it can use binary search, which is *enormously* faster on lists of 50k elements. You pay a cost when you sort the list, but you gain faster searching. This is what the `-sorted` option enables (you may also need to specify how the list has been sorted, which determines what sort of comparisons are used; the default is also the default sorting order used by `lsort`).

```
# Try to not do this too often!
set sorted_exclusion_list [lsort $exclusion_list]

# Now this is fast
if { [lsearch -exact -sorted $sorted_exclusion_list $cell ] >= 0 } { return 0 }
```

---

Algorithmically, `lsort` is O(N log N), `lsearch` is O(N), and `lsearch -sorted` is O(log N). 50k elements is quite big enough that this matters.

Also, the `in` expression operator *only* does linear searching. At the moment; it's allowed to change if we store some (hidden) metadata about ordering, but we've not done that yet (and might never do so).